# What is meant by a vector representation?

Tags: terminology, vectors, group-theory, tensor-calculus, representation-theory

Physicists often talk about a vector representation. For example, the first comment to this answer says:

> That the $(1/2,1/2)$ representation corresponds to a vector irreducible representation of the Lorentz group is not obvious.

From a mathematical point of view all representation are valued in vector spaces so it's somewhat confusing to talk of vector representations. That is all reps are

> $G \rightarrow Aut V$

Where $V$ is some vector space.

My first inclination is that it's simply a physicists way of speaking to distinguish between spinorial reps (which, rather than going from G, goes from the universal cover of G, which in the case of the Lorentz group is its double cover) and ordinary 'vector' representations, which goes directly from G.

Is this on the right track, or is there more to calling a rep, a vector rep?

Comment: Note that a [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(mathematics_and_physics)) means many different things in mathematics & physics depending on context. Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155878/2451

Comment: You might be overthinking this a bit... When saying $5\;\mathrm m$ and $(3\;\mathrm m\;,4\;\mathrm m)$ it is fairly convenient, although not a hundred percent semantically fitting,  to call the latter a *vector representation* rather than the former. A quick and easily understood use of words. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @qmechanic: maybe so in physics; but it has a precise definition in mathematics.

Comment: @steeven: you might be right, but it's nevertheless not 'quick and easily understood' to me (my background is in mathematics rather than physics - though I have a masters in physics) so this language is potentially confusing. Why do you call (3m,5m) a vector rep, and 3m not?

Comment: Because for "non-mathematicians" like me, the term "vector" is intuitively understood as an *arrow*. 5m is therefore different from any multiple coordinate representations such as (3m,4m), because they can be drawn (or at least imagined) as arrows on a piece of paper.

Comment: @Steeven: ok; even for mathematicians like me, vectors are thought of as arrows; tangent vectors are arrows attached to a point - or position vectors as they're often known; but we also have an axiomatic description. Given your description does this not mean that (3m,5m) can be thought of as two separate arrows?

Comment: How would that be two arrows? It is two coordinates that define one arrow. I don't understand what your mean here.

Comment: @steeven: we probably have two different pictures in mind, hence the difference; I was associating an arrow with (5m); and since (3m,5m) has two occurrences, two arrows; you can define an arrow in any number of dimensions - so I'm not clear what you mean here.

Comment: I agree, it sounds like we have different imaginations of the very idea of a number. Now, to see it from my perspective, consider this question: What do you need to draw an arrow (in 2D)? The answer is: 2 things. Length and angle. Or equivalently, how far "out" and how far "up". Each of those two "things" are not themselves vectors. That is how I see a scalar. As a building block in ie a vector. But not as a vector.

Comment: @steeven: ok, I see what you're driving at - at least with this; when you mentioned 'coordinate representations' I understood that as with coordinate axes x,y,z which is why I was disputing it required two bits of information, here it would require as many bits of information as the space has dimensions; when I physically think of a vector, I nusually think of it as you do - direction and magnitude - this is the natural description.

Comment: Exactly. The coordinate representation is for me the full linear combination: $$3\vec i+4 \vec j$$Here the basis vectors are vectors, but the coordinates themselves, namely 3 and 4,  are not.

Comment: @steeven: mathematically speaking they're in the dual vector space, so they're vectors; but again, I see what you're driving at - they're not 'physical' vectors.

Comment: @steeven: its also occurred to me that the appropriate physics terminology for what you were describing by two bits of information ie 'length and angle' is degrees of freedom; for angle, we have two degrees, and then radius gives another degree (we can vary the length of the arrow); and this matches the degrees of freedom for space thought of as a  cartesian space ie with a cartesian grid x, y, z; its probably where the concept dimension originated from and which is part of the notion of manifold.

Comment: Degrees of freedom can be a synonym for dimensions. I agree. This is somewhat off-topic on this question, though.

Answer (score 3):

A similar thing happens in mathematics as well. Although $V\otimes \cdots \otimes V \otimes V^* \otimes \cdots \otimes V^*$ is a vector space, in many contexts its elements are not called vectors but tensors, whereas the name *vector* is reserved for elements of $V$.

For the Lorentz group we have, for example, the trivial representation, which we call a scalar (even if it is a vector, trivially). The spinor representations are best identified as spinors rather than as vectors (although they are vectors, of course). We can use the name *vector* for the representation $(1/2,1/2)$, because it acts on the vectors in the physical space-time. For higher spin, we have other specific names to identify the representations. For example, just as in mathematics, the tensor products of our *vector* representation are usually called tensors.

Comment: +1: this suggests that spinors don't act on space time, is that right?

Comment: @MoziburUllah Yes, or being a bit more precise: the spinor representations do not correspond to the space-time or it tangent spaces

Comment: It is misleading to even wrong to think/say that spinors (better said spinorial fields) do not act on flat/curved spacetime. The concept of spinor bundle (briefly touched upon by R. Wald in his chapter 13) explains everything, starting with the SL(2,C) principle fiber bundle over spacetime.

Comment: @DanielC Hmm, it seems strange to me to even talk about spinors (or spinorial fields) acting on anything. What do you mean, exactly?