# Infinitesimal translation of the scalar field (QFT)

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, field-theory

I'm following my professor's notes on QFT, and I cannot understand this passage. It's about an infinitesimal transformation for the coordinates of a scalar field $\phi$. The passage reads:

> Let us consider an infinitesimal spacetime translation $$x^{\nu} \to  x^{' \nu} = x^{\nu} - \epsilon^{\nu}$$ whence
> $$\phi_i (x) \to \phi'_i (x) = \phi'_i (x' + \epsilon) = \phi_i (x)  + \epsilon^{\nu} \partial_{\nu} \phi_i(x)$$

I really don't get why he goes to $\phi'$ and I don't get the very last two terms of the equality (the scalar fields plus the derivative).

Can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coordinate Transformation of Scalar Fields in QFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77410/)

Comment: @TobiasFünke I was indeed reading that answer. It's still not clear to me why $\phi' = \phi$ though

Comment: By definition, scalar fields transform under a Poincare transformations as $\phi'(x):=\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x)$, so if $\Lambda x:=x-\lambda$, then $\phi'(x)=\phi(x+\lambda)$. This is the active view point.